# Speech recognition in Android

Tags: java, android

I am working on speech recognition and need some sample programs.

Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let me cut and paste a bit to show you what code you will need.

EDIT: you can also download a handy abstract class from [this project](https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib/blob/master/library/src/root/gast/speech/SpeechRecognizingAndSpeakingActivity.java).

You will need this intent (parameterize as you see fit):

```
public Intent getRecognizeIntent(String promptToUse, int maxResultsToReturn)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, maxResultsToReturn);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, promptToUse);
    return intent;
}
```

Then you need to send your intent to the speech recognition activity like so,

```
public void gatherSpeech(String prompt)
{
    Intent recognizeIntent = getRecognizeIntent(prompt);
    try
    {
        startActivityForResult(recognizeIntent, SpeechGatherer.VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException actNotFound)
    {
        Log.w(D_LOG, "did not find the speech activity, not doing it");
    }
}
```

Then you will need to have your activity handle the speech result:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    Log.d("Speech", "GOT SPEECH RESULT " + resultCode + " req: "
        + requestCode);
    if (requestCode == SpeechGatherer.VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE)
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            ArrayList<String> matches = data
                            .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            Log.d(D_LOG, "matches: ");
            for (String match : matches)
            {
                Log.d(D_LOG, match);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how to detect punctuation marks? I tried out the code above and tried saying question mark for "?", comma for "," , point for "." , nothing worked.

Comment: There is no way to recognize punctuation unfortunately.

Comment: Google doesn't return punctuation.  For example if I say "Hey, what are you doing?", one of the interpretations from Google will likely be "hey what are you doing".  No comma, no question mark.

Comment: I keep getting 0 activity, any clues?

Comment: @gregm pls can you say How can I get my voice from that class.I mean I want to get my voice in mp3 format

Comment: @Ersin You might want to look at the SpeechRecognizer class and its listener. I believe you have access to the raw data.

Answer (score 6):

For more info see:

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/speech-input.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/VoiceRecognition.html

Answer (score 0):

First need to Showing google speech input dialog like so

```
 /**
 * Showing google speech input dialog
 * */
private void promptSpeechInput() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
            getString(R.string.speech_prompt));
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

then need to receiving speech input like so.

```
 /**
 * Receiving speech input
 * */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                ArrayList<String> result = data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                txtSpeechInput.setText(result.get(0));
            }
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

and need to set REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT

```
  private final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 100;
```