# Voice recognition

Tags: android, voice-recognition, voice

I try to search about voice recognition in android. Almost of search result, I have only founded the voice recognition api which provided by Google. Moreover, I want to know which other api that provide for android. Because I would to use my voice recognition to search in my file.
Could anyone solve this problem or give me some suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know almost nothing about Android, but I've visited this page in the SDK docs before: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/speech-input.html  You or someone else may find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question in stack overflow which is similar to yours and it has one answer which might be helpful to you..

[Speech recognition in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042752/speech-recognition-in-android/3047498#3047498)