# Integrate Google Voice Recognition in Android app

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, google-voice, google-voice-search

I want to introduce a new feature into my app: **permanent voice recognition**.

First of all I followed these posts:

[Voice recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213308/voice-recognition)

[Speech recognition in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042752/speech-recognition-in-android/3047498#3047498)

[Offline Speech Recognition In Android (JellyBean)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616994/offline-speech-recognition-in-android-jellybean)

and more others, plus other posts from different websites.

**Problem:**
What actually I'm trying to do is to have a permanent voice recognition without displaying google's voice activity. For example: When I start the application the voice recognition should start and listen. When the recognizer matches some words then my app will do different actions accordingly. I do not like to press a button every time I want to do voice recognition, and also I do not like to appear anything on the screen to talk to. Can I do that?

Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 6):

Android can use voice recognition without any GUI. You can use [SpeechRecognizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html) class to do this. But google doesn't allow you to use theirs voice tools for long time recognition. After 5-7 seconds of silence it will be stopped.

If you want to use limited comands vocabulary, you can use offline continious recognition like [PocketSphinx](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-android).

Answer (score 0):

For long time recognition you can use:

```
intent.putExtra("android.speech.extra.DICTATION_MODE", true);
```

Comment: Provide more details why do you think this extra switches on "long time recognition", e.g. where is it documented as having such function.