# How to add Continues Speech Recognition in my Android Application?

Tags: android, speech-to-text

I am try to implement Continues Speech Recognition in my Android Application.  I have followed  this [Link](http://loris-bachert.blogspot.in/2014/04/android-continous-speech-recognition.html) coding. this Continues Speech Recognition worked before two days. But now Speech Recognition not working good it will be taking more time for speech listening. how to resolve this problem.  Please guide me. Thanks

Recognition coding:

```
// starts the service
    protected void startListening() {
        try {
            initSpeech();
            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            //intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");
             if (!intent.hasExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE))
            {
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,
                        "com.dummy");
            }
            sr.startListening(intent);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            Log.d("SpeechRecognitionService", "Bei der Initialisierung des SpeechRecognizers ist ein Fehler aufgetreten");
        }
    }

    // stops the service
    protected void stopListening() {
        if (sr != null) {
            sr.stopListening();
            sr.cancel();
            sr.destroy();
        }
        sr = null;
    }

    protected void initSpeech() {
        if (sr == null) {
            sr = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
            if (!SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(context)) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Speech Recognition is not available",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
            sr.setRecognitionListener(VoiceRecognitionListener.getInstance());
        }
    }
```

User starts speaking

```
public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
            System.out.println("Starting to listen");
        }

        public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) { }

        // User finished speaking
        public void onEndOfSpeech() {
            System.out.println("Waiting for result...");
        }
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? In that case, what error?

Comment: no error.. but speech listening taking more time @ Polarbear

Comment: taking more time how?

Comment: speech listening started. but result we will be coming 3 to 4 minutes.. but before two day result will be came 50 to 60 sec

Comment: I don't understand the problem

Comment: please refer above code @polar onBeginningOfSpeech() will be stared but  onEndOfSpeech will be taking  4 to 5 minutes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116344/discussion-between-polarbear0106-and-raj).

Comment: check this thread too, maybe it can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24909280/integrate-google-voice-recognition-in-android-app

Comment: Your problem may be related to one of the bugs linked from the answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/38150312/1256219

Comment: @brandall i have tried your workaround solution but still now i am facing this problem.

Comment: Your implementation will no longer work as Google's recognizer is completely broken. If you don't speak within a short period of the recognition starting, then `onResults()` is never called. `stopSpeech()` is broken, as well as `rms`. For continuous recognition, look at using PocketSphinx

Comment: @brandall thanks for your reply. hear after i am try to implement PocketSphinx. but i have get some solution for RecognizerIntent..

Comment: i have changed this line  intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);    to   intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");

Comment: LANGUAGE_‌​MODEL_WEB_SEARCH   response taking 3 to 5min      EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US"  response 1 to 2 min

Comment: I think you'll find it depends on ambient noise. The implementation should obviously send the results within seconds, so something is very broken. `EXTRA_LANGUAGE` & `EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL` are different variables.

Comment: @brandall.. please guide me how to resolve this problem. we are published our app in app store. our app fully based on Speech Recognizer

Comment: There is no fix I'm afraid, thousands of developers will be in the same situation, including me. All you can do is use a different recognition provider (search Google for java voice recognition) until Google fix it.

Comment: thanks for your support @ brandall once you are fixed this issues please post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to reducing the time between speaking and receiving the results.

Request PARTIAL RESULTS as these are delivered before the FULL RESULTS.

I used these EXTRAS:-

```
mRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
mRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().trim());
mRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, this.getPackageName());
mRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
mRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS, true);
mRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, 100);

mRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 3);

mSongSpeechRecognitionListener = new SongSpeechRecognitionListener(mRippleBackground, mFloatingActionButton);

mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(mSongSpeechRecognitionListener);
```

Then in partial results

```
public void onPartialResults(final Bundle partialResults) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onPartialResults()");

    final List<String> partialResultList = partialResults.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);

for (final String result : partialResultList) {

    if (result.isEmpty()) {
    } else {
        mPartialResults++;
        if (mPartialResults == mPartialResultsMAX) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onPartialResults() EXECUTE");
            mFloatingActionButton.setEnabled(true);
            mAsyncTask.execute(result);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I set `mPartialResultsMAX` to 2 as it seemed the first partial result was only ever a single word

When you receive PARTIAL RESULTS you may want to cancel the speech recogniser.

Comment: thanks for your coding. i have update your coding in our application it will be working good..